# Overloading == compiling error c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I made a simple `struct` named coord to hold , well coordinates , and I wanted to check if two coords were equal , so I looked how to do a proper operator overloading in another thread and came up with this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct coord{
    int x;
    int y;

    inline bool operator==(const coord& lhs, const coord& rhs){
        if(lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    coord a,b;
    a.x=5;
    a.y=5;
    b.x=a.x;
    b.y=a.y;
    if(a==b){
        cout<<"Working"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But at compiling I get a massive error who looks like :

```
g++ -c -o obj/main.o main.cpp -I../include
main.cpp:8:62: error: ‘bool coord::operator==(const coord&, const coord&)’ must take exactly one argument
     inline bool operator==(const coord& lhs, const coord& rhs){
                                                          ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:24:6: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘coord’ and ‘coord’)
  if(a==b){
      ^
main.cpp:24:6: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/iosfwd:40:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ios:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream:39,
             from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator==(const fpos<_SenttateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
```

This goes on for a variety of other std things as `‘coord’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’` or `‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’` , the whole error being to long [here it is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QLvu3H7K).

I hope someone understands whats going wrong here and can explain it to me

Comment: "massive error", you sir have not run into a templating error of several hundred lines, this is nothing.

Comment: You need to make the function a friend function to take 2 parameters.

Comment: @Borgleader, How about [1.5 GB with a max 256 B source file](http://tgceec.tumblr.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of choices to get around the problem:

**Member function**

```
inline bool operator==(const coord& rhs) const {
    return (this->x == rhs.x && this->y == rhs.y);
}
```

When you use

```
if(a==b){
```

the function is called on the object `a` and the argument to the function is `b`.

**Non-member function**

This can be defined outside the definition of `struct coord`.

```
struct coord{
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator==(const coord& lhs, const coord& rhs){
   return (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y);
}
```

When you use

```
if(a==b){
```

the function is called with `a` for `lhs` and `b` for `rhs`.

Comment: It's already inlined as appearing in the `struct`. I was about giving an answer preceeding with a `friend` declaration, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @AndyG I absolutely agree. Unfortunately R.Sahu doesn't explain that much about here it should be defined outside of the struct/class.

Comment: Careful when you use the word "friend", since that is also a keyword. In this case, if the function is of the stand-alone, two parameter flavor, it can access the public data members of `coord` like any other function. Operators are just functions with funny names.